# How to add leading zeros in sybase ase

Tags: sybase, sap-ase

Need to add leading zeros to column values(varchar) and update it in same table.
ex: 431 as 000431, 5431 as 005431, 64531 as 064531, basically i need to substitute zeros to the data so that it is 6 digits. this is in sybase ase.

thanks

Comment: any better than SELECT RIGHT('000000'+ CONVERT(VARCHAR,actuals),6) FROM nbr_actuals

Answer (score 3):

If you can't use `LPAD()`, **and** the source number is an `integer`, this solution is maybe a little nicer than yours:

```
RIGHT(1000000+Number, 6)
```

But, as yours, it produces unexpected results if the value is negative or has more than 6 digits.

Answer (score 1):

In case you're running  ASE 16.0SP01 or later, you can use the built-in function LPAD(). Otherwise, the expression you quoted is the way to go (which you could wrap into a SQL function to make it easier to use)

Comment: Thank you for the response, I am working on ASE 12 :) I went with the same expression.